# Create a customer list in Google Ads using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api

The goal is to take data we have and create google ads' Customer List with it automatically, using NodeJS, specifically this:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/remarketing/audience-segments/customer-match/get-started#create-customer

I looked into documentation for google-ads-api, googleapi and a couple of other libraries but found nothing helpful. I'm also pretty new with Google Ads API, so I might be missing something obvious.

There seems to be no good examples or documentation on this (except the PHP, C# etc ones in the above link), so if it's not possible in NodeJS I would love to have a concrete confirmation and/or explanation as to why.